# remove all the extra lines from the array in mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I want to remove the extra lines or "\n\r" & "\n" from the array but my solution is not working. Please provide the correct function or dataweave for this.

input (json array format):

```
 [{"m":"a\n\r",
   "a":"b\n"},
  {"m":"a\r\n",
   "a":"b\n"}]
```

expected output(json array format):

```
 [{"m":"a",
   "a":"b"},
  {"m":"a",
   "a":"b"}]
```

code:

```
    %dw 2.0
    var someSpaceJson = write(payload, "application/json", {"indent":false}) 
    output application/json
    ---
    someSpaceJson replace "\n\r" with ""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `\\` instead of `\` to represent the escape char.

```
%dw 2.0
var someSpaceJson = write(payload, "application/json", {"indent":false}) 
output application/json
---
read((someSpaceJson replace "\\r" with "" replace "\\n" with ""),"application/json")
```

This should give you your desired output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the new lines between the values and only want to remove the trailing `\r`'s and `\n`'s you can use the following. This will also avoid converting JSON to string and back which generally should be avoided.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map ($ mapObject ($$): trim($))
```

However, you need to make sure that all values are `string` or `null`. If that is not the case you can add those conditions in the mapObject function itself.

[image]